# Real time clock display in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create real time clock using Tkinter and time library. I have created a class but somehow I am not able to figure out my problem.

My code

```
from tkinter import *

import time

root = Tk()

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time1 = ''
        self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.mFrame = Frame()
        self.mFrame.pack(side=TOP,expand=YES,fill=X)
        self.watch = Label (self.mFrame, text=self.time2, font=('times',12,'bold'))
        self.watch.pack()
        self.watch.after(200,self.time2)

obj1 = Clock()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should provide the stacktrace you get, or describe the problem you are facing.

Comment: Do you get a error message? Can you post it, please?

Answer (score 3):

Second parameter of [`after()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) should be a `function` -when you are giving any- but you are giving a `str` object. Hence you are getting an error.

```
from tkinter import *    
import time

root = Tk()

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time1 = ''
        self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.mFrame = Frame()
        self.mFrame.pack(side=TOP,expand=YES,fill=X)

        self.watch = Label(self.mFrame, text=self.time2, font=('times',12,'bold'))
        self.watch.pack()

        self.changeLabel() #first call it manually

    def changeLabel(self): 
        self.time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.watch.configure(text=self.time2)
        self.mFrame.after(200, self.changeLabel) #it'll call itself continuously

obj1 = Clock()
root.mainloop()
```

Also note that:

> The callback is only called once for each call to this method. To keep
>   calling the callback, you need to reregister the callback inside
>   itself.